# Adding the array values when uploaded from an excel fie

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, excel

Hi i am Importing the value from excel sheet to MySql Database . Before doing so i need to do some validation

Here is my excel Sheet
[image: Excel Sheet]

The Code below is used for validation.

```
            $item_data = array();
            $this->load->library('excel');
            $objPHPExcel  = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($input_csv);
            $highestRow = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow();

            for($i=2;$i<=$highestRow;$i++)
            {
                $col='B';

                $sl_num=$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A'.$i)->getValue();
                $Export_Sl_No=$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($col.''.$i)->getValue();
                $Import_Sl_No=$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell(++$col.''.$i)->getValue();
                $Quantity=$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell(++$col.''.$i)->getValue();
                $UOM=$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell(++$col.''.$i)->getValue();
                $CIF_INR=$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell(++$col.''.$i)->getValue();
                $CIF_USD=$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell(++$col.''.$i)->getValue();


                $item_data[$Import_Sl_No]=$Quantity;

                $importSLNo = $item_data[$Import_Sl_No];


                if( $importSLNo != null){
                    $item_data[$Import_Sl_No]=$importSLNo+$Quantity;

                }
                else {
                    $item_data[$Import_Sl_No]=$Quantity;
                }
            }

            print_r($item_data); 
            exit;
```

When i do **print_r($item_data);** i get the output like This

```
     Array ( [3] => 724 [4] => 624 )
```

But the actual output what i need is

```
    Array ( [3] => 374 [4] => 355 )  i.e adding the Quantity for same Item_Sl_No
```

Here an instance about the calculation

```
 Item_Sl_No       Quantity
     3            12
     4            43
     4            312
     3            362
```

**For  3 it should be 12 + 362 = 374 
For  4 it should be 43 + 312 = 355**

So the output what i need is

```
Array ( [3] => 374 [4] => 355 )
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
$item_data = array();
$this->load->library('excel');
$objPHPExcel  = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($input_csv);
$highestRow = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow();

for($i=2;$i<=$highestRow;$i++)
{
    $col='B';

    $sl_num=$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A'.$i)->getValue();
    $Export_Sl_No=$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($col.''.$i)->getValue();
    $Import_Sl_No=trim($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell(++$col.''.$i)->getValue());
    $Quantity=trim($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell(++$col.''.$i)->getValue());
    $UOM=$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell(++$col.''.$i)->getValue();
    $CIF_INR=$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell(++$col.''.$i)->getValue();
    $CIF_USD=$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell(++$col.''.$i)->getValue();

    if(array_key_exists($Import_Sl_No, $item_data))
    {
      $item_data[$Import_Sl_No]=$item_data[$Import_Sl_No]+$Quantity;
    }
    else
    {
          $item_data[$Import_Sl_No]=$Quantity;
    }
}

print_r($item_data);
exit;
```

**What went wrong?**

You slightly overdid it. This part:

```
$item_data[$Import_Sl_No]=$Quantity;
```

on second loop was erasing quantities from first loop which you tried to store temporarly before they could be used as a basis for adding next quantity.

And this part:

```
$importSLNo = $item_data[$Import_Sl_No];
```

was basically making `$importSLNo` equal `$Quantity`. So at the end:

```
$item_data[$Import_Sl_No]=$importSLNo+$Quantity;
```

was basically:

```
$item_data[$Import_Sl_No]=2*$Quantity;
```

So you were erasing all quantities for `Import_Sl_No` except the one from last loop and you were doubling it.

Comment: Could you pls do `var_dump($Import_Sl_No)` and `var_dump($Quantity)` inside a loop and check if quantities values are correctly read from Excel for all loops?

Comment: yeah am getting the values `float(3) float(12) float(4) float(43) float(4) float(312) float(3) float(362)`

Comment: Try running on your environment this code which is manual step-by-step loop with your data: https://eval.in/937877

Comment: @NewBie: one more idea. Maybe there are spaces or other characters read from file preventing `array_key_exist` from detecting existing value. I added `trim` around `$Import_Sl_No` value and updated answer. Try new version pls.